# postgres groupby to nested select by date

Tags: postgresql, query

I want to create report how much message per day, so this is my query :

```
select 
date(cm.created_at) as `date`, 
count(1) as total_message, 
(select count(1) from chat_message where is_send = 't') as outbound,
(select count(1) from chat_message where is_send != 't') as inbound
from chat_message cm
group by date(created_at);
```

but in this condition `outbound` and `inbound` will count from table not affected by `group by`.

so how to solve my query so it will affected by `group by`?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't support backticks as name delimiters, nor does it have a `date()` function. Are you sure you are using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  d,
  total_message,
  (select count(1) from chat_message p where p.status='t' and date(p.created_at) = tanggal) outbound,
  (select count(1) from chat_message p where p.status !='t' and date(p.created_at) = tanggal) inbound
from
(
  select 
      date(created_at) as d, 
      count(1) as total_message
  from chat_message 
  group by date(created_at)
)tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a `with` virtual table to mark message then sum in/out grouping by first field (`date`).
I think this code is more readable and clear to understand then use subquery.

```sql
with m as (
    select
        date(created_at) as "date",
        case when is_send = 't' then 1 else 0 end as outbound,
        case when is_send != 't' then 1 else 0 end as inbound
    from chat_message
    )
select 
    "date",
    count(1) as total_message,
    sum(outbound) as outbound,
    sum(inbound) as inbound
from m 
group by 1
;
```

*PS: I haven't tested the query, it may have any mistakes.*